How to delete specific autofill form data entries from Edge
In Edge, I want to delete some of these form entries ("Saved data"):

NB: this question doesn't concern the list of last used Website addresses in the Address Bar of Edge. It's only about the forms with input fields inside the area displaying the Web pages.
The only setting I can find is in the Wallet settings (edge://wallet/settings) > Personal info > Save and fill basic info, which stops saving and suggesting form values, but there's no way to delete an individual entry:

How to manage/delete form entries in Edge?
I saw this answer which explains to use the Edge Settings > Advanced Settings > Autofill Settings > Manage form entries, but in my Edge version (127.0.2651.74 (Official build) (64-bit)), I don't see anything related (nothing for Advanced, Autofill or Form):


The linked answer is only applicable to Legacy Edge (EdgeHTML) from before the transition to the Chromium engine.

Here is an appropriate article.

To delete one specific autofill form data entry for Edge, it's the same solution as for any Chromium-based navigator (see Chrome answer):

Type in the field
Use the down arrow key (or the mouse hover) to highlight the suggestion entry you want to delete
Press shift + Delete

It also works for autofill data in the Location bar and in the Search bar.

Doesn't work for me. In the address bar I start typing and autofill suggests a list of urls. I use the arrow key to select an entry and I press Ctrl+Delete but nothing happens (version 128.0.2739.54  of Edge for Business)

Doesn't work for deleting items in autofill on fields on Edge for Business v131.0.2903.70. Other ideas?

The solution used to work for Edge for Business, but I can't test now because my company has disabled "Save and fill basic info". In fact, in August 2024, the solution used to work, but the deleted content was restored automatically after a few days! No idea why.

As suggested by @Ramhound, to delete all form entries, there is this solution (Microsoft > Save or forget passwords in Microsoft Edge):

Edge > Settings > Delete browsing data:


Check "Autofill form data (includes forms and cards)":



